# Remove "Remove" Link in Case Team Related List

Tags: case, case-teams

Is is possible to remove the **Remove** link from **Case Team** related list in Salesforce? I've been trying to search about this all over the Internet but found no luck.

Comment: Is it a VF Page or standard salesforce layout?

Comment: It's a standard salesforce layout.